# ¿Imprimir los dias del mes con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy probando a crear un calendario con Javascript para refrescar , pues bien tengo una pregunta.

Actualmente obtengo todos los días de cada mes con el siguiente método.

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        }
```

Pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacer el tipico calendario , realmente lo unico que me interesa es el formato.

Como podría hacer para imprimir un mes de calendario sabiendo los dias ?

```
for(var  i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        console.log(daysInMonth(i, years));
    }

    function daysInMonth(month, year) {
        return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }
```

Comment: Querés visualizar un calendario como [este](http://www.free-printable-calendar.com/printable-calendars-images/may-2018-calendar.gif)?

Comment: Moment.js te muchas opciones de formatos, entra y revisa la documentación. http://momentjs.com/ . Hace unos días estuve utilizando otra en curso, en cuanto la encuentre te digo. Pero moment.js da mucho juego

Comment: También puedes usar FormatJS

Comment: @Kleith busco exactamente eso

Comment: Voy a revisar MomentJS y FormatJS